# Clarification needed on DNS propagation

Tags: dns, nameservers, server-administration

When changing the nameservers for a domain, will there ever be a time in which it points to neither the old nameservers nor the new nameservers? If so, why does this occur?

---

For a little context, the reason I ask is because I just did this, the A-record and nameservers are coming up correctly when I get the DNS info, I verified the site on the new server AND the old server was running by adding them to my local machine's hosts file, but I got a "site not found" error in Chrome for about an hour before it came up correctly. (meaning, SOMETHING changed, but why didn't it just change immediately to the new nameservers?)

Comment: Of course it's possible if you delete the old NS records first, reload the zone, then add new NS records, then reload the zone again, but this would be an unusual thing to do. Usually you would replace the NS records with new ones in a single change.

Comment: Right, that's why I'm confused, because I did it in one single change, so theoretically it would either route visitors to the old server or the new server, with no "in between"